# Java Hibernate Search Like Query - Injection Protection - Parameter Binding?

Tags: java, hibernate, search, code-injection

I have a hibernate search which allows searching for jobs through their description. This uses a like query to match up any words that are found in the description with the words being searched for. This code below is working, however is vulnerable to injection in the form of ‘ or ‘1’=’1 being typed into the search box. This will output the whole table which of course I do not want.

```
log.debug("REST request to search Jobs for query {}", query);
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Query a = session.createQuery("select jobs from Jobs jobs where jobs.description like '%" + query + "%'");
return a.list();
```

I believe I need to use parameter binding to correct this, however I can't seem to get it working. Below is the some of the code I have tried however I simply get a 500 internal server error. I can't find any examples using the like query so this is causing some confusion. I am probably overlooking something obvious as I have never used hibernate before.

```
Query a = session.createQuery("select jobs from Jobs jobs where jobs.description like '%" + query + "%'");
a.setParameter("description", a);
return a.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use named parameters with JPA:

```
Query a = session.createQuery("select jobs from Jobs jobs where jobs.description like '%:queryParam%'");
a.setParameter("queryParam", query);
```

`setParameter` takes the name of your parameter wich you prefix with `:` in your query as the first argument and the value you want to put into it as the second argument.